# Checkboxes not visible in jQuery datatable second time

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am binding the table with a callback by using an UpdatePanel.

Once my button click code-behind runs completely, I call a script on the aspx page by using Scriptmanager.ClientScriptblock()...
and in the invoked JavaScript function I append rows to the DataTable.

On the first load it adds the checkboxes as the first column, but on the second call they are not visible and are shown only when I sort the table.

Why are they visible only after sorting the table?

I am appending rows to tbody as follows:

```
$("#bodyListLetter tr").remove(); // first removing tr and then add.
$('#bodyListLetter').append(Rows);
```

Table initialisation code:

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example2')) {
   table = $('#example2').DataTable();
}
else {
   $('#example2').DataTable({
   "searching": false,
   "retrieve": false,
   "paging": false,
   "ordering": true,
   "info": false,

        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',                       
            targets: 0
        }],

        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },

        order: [[1, 'asc']]
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to invalidate the rows and redraw. This solved the problem.

```
var table = $('#example2').DataTable();

    table.rows().invalidate().draw();
```